# ionic-nav-view with 'next' option

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

As I am advancing with Ionic programming, I have come to find this problem which I don't know how to solve best. The thing is that I want to show on the header (or preferably on the sub-header) this:

< yesterday    TODAY     tomorrow>

So users will start the App on today's page and can navigate to previous and next days (it is a calendar-like app). I was planning to do this using two buttons for 'yesterday' and 'tomorrow' and just change text for buttons and title upon page change using the controller. Nevertheless, I have found out the ion-nav-view and was wondering if, somehow, I can adapt it to mimic my desired behavior. It does include the back option but not the forward one... The question is, can this be done?. Has anyone managed to do something like I am attempting here?.

Thanks in advance.

Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that shows the solution I have reached. It does work for me.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div align-title="center" class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <button class="button button-clear ">Menú</button>
      <button class="button button-clear">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bar bar-subheader">
      <button class="button icon-left button-clear button-dark" ng-hide="hidePrevious" ng-click="previousDay()"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> {{previousDayTitle}} </button>
      <h1 class="title"><span style="font-size:35px"> {{todayTitle}} </span></h1>
      <button class="button icon-left button-clear button-dark" ng-hide="hideNext" ng-click="nextDay()"> {{nextDayTitle}} <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i></button>

    </div>
    <ion-content class="has-header has-subheader">jjjh sss
      <br> sasas asasa
      <br> sasas
    </ion-content>
    <!--<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="isChecked">Programa</ion-checkbox>
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="isChecked">Alternativo</ion-checkbox>
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="isChecked">Taurina</ion-checkbox>
    </div>-->
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Ionic';

  // 20 August - 27  August, both included
  firstFairDay = new Date(2016, 7, 20);
  lastFairDay = new Date(2016, 7, 27);

  now = new Date(2018, 1, 1);

  weekDays = ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'];

  if (now.getTime() >= lastFairDay.getTime()) {
    $scope.hidePrevious = false;
    $scope.hideNext = true;
    now = new Date(lastFairDay);
    todayDayOfWeek = weekDays[now.getDay()];
    todayDayNumber = now.getDate();
    $scope.previousDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() - 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber - 1);
  } else if (now.getTime() <= firstFairDay.getTime()) {
    $scope.hidePrevious = true;
    $scope.hideNext = false;
    now = new Date(firstFairDay);
    todayDayOfWeek = weekDays[now.getDay()];
    todayDayNumber = now.getDate();
    $scope.nextDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() + 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber + 1);
  } else {
    $scope.hidePrevious = false;
    $scope.hideNext = false;
    todayDayOfWeek = weekDays[now.getDay()];
    todayDayNumber = now.getDate();
    $scope.previousDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() - 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber - 1);
    $scope.nextDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() + 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber + 1);
  }

  $scope.todayTitle = todayDayOfWeek + " " + todayDayNumber;

  $scope.previousDay = function() {
    if (now.getTime() === firstFairDay.getTime()) {
      // Do nothing
    } else {
      now.setDate(now.getDate() - 1);
      todayDayNumber = now.getDate();
      todayDayOfWeek = weekDays[now.getDay()];

      if (now.getTime() === firstFairDay.getTime()) {
        $scope.hidePrevious = true;
        $scope.hideNext = false;
        $scope.todayTitle = todayDayOfWeek + " " + todayDayNumber;
        $scope.nextDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() + 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber + 1);
      } else {
        $scope.hidePrevious = false;
        $scope.hideNext = false;
        $scope.previousDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() - 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber - 1);
        $scope.todayTitle = todayDayOfWeek + " " + todayDayNumber;
        $scope.nextDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() + 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber + 1);
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.nextDay = function() {
    if (now.getTime() === lastFairDay.getTime()) {
      // Do nothing
    } else {
      now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);

      todayDayNumber = now.getDate();
      todayDayOfWeek = weekDays[now.getDay()];

      if (now.getTime() === lastFairDay.getTime()) {
        $scope.hidePrevious = false;
        $scope.hideNext = true;
        $scope.previousDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() - 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber - 1);
        $scope.todayTitle = todayDayOfWeek + " " + todayDayNumber;
      } else {
        $scope.hidePrevious = false;
        $scope.hideNext = false;
        $scope.previousDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() - 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber - 1);
        $scope.todayTitle = todayDayOfWeek + " " + todayDayNumber;
        $scope.nextDayTitle = weekDays[(((now.getDay() + 1) % 7) + 7) % 7] + " " + (todayDayNumber + 1);
      }
    }
  };



});
```

Cheers

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the solution. Up for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

@kankamuso: 
For ionic 2, you can try to create new project with tabs template by the following command.

```
ionic start tabProject tabs --v2
```

Read more from http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#tabs

For ionic 1, please refer here.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/

Comment: Thanks @trungj18 but, isn't space limited on a tabbed page?. I mean, I have to include 8 tabs each with a text title consisting of day of week plus number o day of month... Also, I want the current element to be centered ( the selected day)...

Comment: I think it is because the device width will not be sufficient to have 8 tabs mate :D If you want to archive extend to 8 tabs, can try radio button or checkbox http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#radio-buttons

Comment: I am afraid this would not solve my problem.. I just need a mode to navigate through a lot of pages and the one in the middle of the bar would be showing on the contents space.

Comment: I will tell you how it hora. Thanks

Comment: Nothing, adding many tabs will just clog the bar, no swipe or other mechanism to keep UI clean and simple. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can try slide box http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/

Comment: Definitely, this is a better starting point. Nevertheless, I don't really like the dots at the bottom... I have managed to create hand-crafted code that does exactly what I need using plain Jaavascript and AngularJS... Thanks for your help!.